# Why is the class probability coming out as 0 when within the for-loop it is being calculated correctly?

Tags: python

I have isolated the bug in

```
def classify_single_elem(self, X_elem):
    Y_dict = {}
#   print ('self.label' ,self.labels)      ok
    for label in self.labels:
        class_probability = self.class_probabilities[label]
#        print ('class probability' ,class_probability)   okok
        for ii in range(0,len(X_elem)):
            relative_feature_values = self.nb_dict[label][ii]
            if X_elem[ii] in relative_feature_values.keys():
                # ok
                class_probability *= relative_feature_values[X_elem[ii]]    
            else:
                # when it gets to here the probability is set to zero
                # which means the dict has zero values
                class_probability *= 0   
        Y_dict[label] = class_probability  
    return self.get_max_value_key(Y_dict)
```

Comment: Sorry, the indentation came out wrong.for ii in range(0,len(X_elem)):
            relative_feature_values = self.nb_dict[label][ii]
            if X_elem[ii] in relative_feature_values.keys():
                # ok
                class_probability *= relative_feature_values[X_elem[ii]]    
            else:
                # when it gets to here the probability is set to zero
                # which means the dict has zero values
                class_probability *= 0   
        Y_dict[label] = class_probability  
    return self.get_max_value_key(Y_dict)

Answer (score 0):

The `class_probability *= 0` is the part that sets the probability to zero.  That happens whenever `X_elem[ii] in relative_feature_values.keys()` is false.

Comment: From the comment in the code snippet, it looks like this is the intended/desired behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps so.  However, all the other sections are labeled as "correct" and the question was "why is the class probability coming out as 0 when within the for-loop it is being calculated correctly?".  So, odd as it may seem, this *is* the answer to the question as asked.   The code has other oddities as well (such as using ``*= 0`` instead of ``= 0``.